# Why Spy is not called in the Mock (Angular 4)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, mocking, observable

Can you please check the test below and see why the spy never gets called? The actual code works fine, however the test is not playing.

If I `spyOn` something inside the `this.apiSrv.fetch` then test passes though. Very strange!

thank you in advance.

manager.service.spec.ts

```js
describe('ManagerService', () => {
    
  const mockClass = new MockClass();
  let spy;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        ManagerService,
        { provide: ApiService, useValue: mockClass},
      ]
    });
    spy = spyOn(mockClass, 'fetch');
  });

    fit('should call server', inject([ManagerService], (service: ManagerService) => {
      service.callServer();
      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }));
    
});
```

manager.service.ts

```js
@Injectable()
export class ManagerService {
  constructor(
    private apiSrv: ApiService,
  ) {}

  public callServer() {
    this.apiSrv.fetch('http://url.com').subscribe( (data) => {
       console.log(data);
    });
  }
}
```

api.service.ts

```js
export class ApiService {
    
  constructor(private http: Http) {}
    
  fetch(resource: string) {
      return this.http.get(resource).map((response) => response.json());
  }
}
```

mock.ts

```js
export class MockClass {
    public fetch(): Observable<any> {
        const expectedResult = {
            items: {
                data: [],
            }
        };
        return Observable.of(expectedResult);
    }
}
```

And the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that `MockClass.fetch` medhod is actually called (not just stubbed) because you chain it with `.subscribe` method otherwise it will cause the error and test won't be passed. So `callThrough` should be used.

```typescript
spy = spyOn(mockClass, 'fetch').and.callThrough();
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
                                   add this
```